# Speakers stop working when I plug in a microphone

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone, speakers

My laptop have it microphone below the touchpad. And when it is on my lap, the microphone muffles.
So I bought a small microphone to plug in the side of the laptop.
But when I plug it, my speakers stop working may because it recognizes as a speaker/microphone combo.
How can I make it work as a microphone only?
Here is a photo of the microphone
[image]

### Update

As suggested I went to realtek control panel, there I see this
[image]
Now I the output is the internal speakers as I wanted, but the microphone is not working

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop is typically showing only one playback device in system settings and automatically switches between built-in speakers and the headphones depending on whether there is anything plugged in the out/combo jack.

Open this window by right-clicking the speaker icon next to your clock and selecting **Sounds** from the menu.

[image: Sound settings in Classic mode]

Your audio card drivers need to support exposing both devices (built-in speakers and combo jack) as separate playback devices to the system. On my system this can be done by opening **Realtek HD Audio Manager**, clicking **Device advanced settings** in the top-right and selecting **Multi-stream mode**.

[image: Select Multi-stream mode]

System sound settings should now show a second playback device and a second recording device and automatically use them as default whenever you plug in the jack.

Now, you'll want to select **Speaker/HP** and click **Set Default** (not the arrow) to use the built-in speakers for playback.

[image: Playback settings in Multi-stream mode]

[image: Recording settings in Multi-stream mode]

Assuming your microphone jack uses common TRRS layout this should be enough.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I only have Realtek Audio Manafer. In a option named "Connector Retasking" I switched to "Microphone Input". but now microphone can't hear nothing. But now i can hear from speakers..

Comment: This should be an equivalent solution for the UWP Realtek app: https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/121801-realtek-audio-console-requires-realtek-hd-uad-driver-9.html#post1555576 Please post a screenshot from your Realtek app in your question.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Hmm, retasking to microphone input would make the connector expect a TRS jack so TRRS jack won't work. I'm just guessing... Try disabling the auto-switching, see what happens when you plug in the microphone then, play around with different options in the Realtek console app.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Windows you can try switching your default output audio device in the audio option. Go to Control Panel, Hardware and Sound, Sound and in playback set as default device the PC speakers and in recording the microphone.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Proper Drivers are not installed on your system.
So, by default, it is recognized as Audio Out or Headphones.
Go to Open Device Manager, click on Audio Device, right-click on it, and then click on update drivers.

Comment: it says they are up too date